# How can I download an array of url images from the web

Tags: swift, xcode, image, tableview, collectionview

Using regular expressions, I extracted the html string, the desired images and put them in an array.

What does the array look like at the moment:

```
var collectionPhotoLinks = [
        "http:static-cdn3.vigbo.tech/u65463/78125/blog/5162255/4423863/57114004/500-codleto-889a051259ba894edee37b8da63ddbe9.jpg",
        "http:static-cdn3.vigbo.tech/u65463/78125/blog/5162255/4423863/57114004/500-codleto-9516ab3514e07bde176f117e70c7ba85.jpg"]
```

I can upload one image

```
func downloadImages () {

    guard let url = URL(string:
        "http:static-cdn3.vigbo.tech/u65463/78125/blog/5162255/4423863/57114004/500-codleto-889a051259ba894edee37b8da63ddbe9.jpg")
            else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.imageView.image = image

            }
        }
    } .resume()
}
```

If the "url" is replaced with an array "collectionPhotoLinks", then respectively xcode requires string not array

So the question follows, how do I load all the images from the array? In the future I will need to send them to tableview or collectionview, but I would like to resolve the issue with this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual is that you download it inside `cellForRowAt` with say [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) , but if you need to pre-download all then you can try

```
let arr = ["url1","urls"]

func downloadImages () {

    let g = DispatchGroup()

    for item in arr {

        guard let url = URL(string:item)
                else { return }

        g.enter()

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {

                //
            }

            g.leave()

        } .resume()
    }

    g.notify(queue: .main) {

        // done 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I haven't studied GCD and Dispatch Queues yet. But after receiving a few answers, I understand that I should study this topic before continuing